# Unable to install dotnet 7 in ubuntu 22.04 in aws code build using buildspec.yml

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to build my project using dotnet7 in aws code build but I am unable to access the dotnet 7 I installed it using these commands

```
sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-7.0
```

but when I run `dotnet --version` it still shows the dotnet 6 version

here is the logs

[image]

[image]

but it still shows dotnet 6

[image]

Comment: In your buildspec yaml you can add a line like 

curl -sSL https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh | bash /dev/stdin --channel STS

unfortunately there has been a change in behavior recently and the path isn't being set correctly (or a similar bug)... still troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 0):

DotNET 7.x is not available in the default AWS CodeBuild environments. To use .NET 7.x in CodeBuild, you need to create a custom build environment with .NET 7.x installed.

Here is one approach, which we are using:

#### Using a Custom Docker Image

You can create a custom Docker image with .NET 7.x installed and use it as your build environment in AWS CodeBuild. Here's a simplified example of how you can create a custom Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2

# Install dependencies
RUN yum install -y tar gzip

# Download and install .NET 7
RUN curl -SL --output dotnet.tar.gz https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/7e149197-6f12-4f19-8c20-3ff0e3a6f2a2/1edee4ac25b870e7d7f584f694fc9e68/dotnet-sdk-7.1.401-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet \
    && tar -zxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet \
    && rm dotnet.tar.gz \
    && ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet

# Set environment variables
ENV DOTNET_ROOT=/usr/share/dotnet
ENV PATH=${PATH}:/usr/share/dotnet
```

Once you have created the Dockerfile, build the Docker image and push it to a container registry (Amazon ECR).

In your AWS CodeBuild project, select the custom Docker image as the build environment.